# Unable to compile class for JSP?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am having html file which is in var/www/file.html
Here i am having link to .jsp file which is in var/lib/tomcat6/webapps.
when i click the jsp file link the browser throws HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP; error while adding the

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
```

namespace to that .jsp file, i am not using any IDE. I have added the mysql_connector.jar file to the bashrc and environment file. Finally, i am using ubuntu 13.1 operating system.

var/www/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
  <a href="demo/create.jsp">Create your iDesk</a>
</body>
</html>
```

var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/demo/first.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create Your Own Meeting</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
if (request.getParameterMap().isEmpty()) {
    //
    // getting parameters here
    //
 %>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: jsp file only won't work, you should have an webapps there.

Comment: You must first make some effort and understand how java web application actually works !

Comment: the jsp file is within webapps only. before adding <%@ import="java.sql.*"> it works fine. after connection of database only it having problem.

Comment: We need more info to help u ... folder structure and html file and the jsp file..

Comment: @Naren now i include the more info about my code while am inserting <%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%> it shows error

Comment: remove that language="java" at second line... and in html your pointing to create.jsp but that is first.jsp... change index.html to index.jsp

Comment: @Naren no its not working, throws same error.

Answer (score 2):

it should be in this format

```
    <%@page import="packageName.*" %>
```

Example:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
```

I assumed ur project name as "Test"

your index.html (it should be under Test folder that means webapps/Test/index.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
  <a href="demo/first.jsp">Create your iDesk</a>
</body>
</html>
```

first.jsp (it should be under webapps/Test/demo/first.jsp)

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create Your Own Meeting</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
out.println("Tester");
if (request.getParameterMap().isEmpty()) {
    //
    // getting parameters here
    //
}
 %>
 </body>
 </html>
</html>
```

Comment: Note the `%>` at the end, in your question above you used just `>` without the `%`.

Comment: when i run this file without <%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%> this namespace it works fine. the problem is inserting the sql namespace only. no problem with directive.

Comment: Have u removed this line from <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;%> from Jsp.. u need to remove it ... above comment is not clear to me..